# javascript for loop to generate forms

Tags: javascript

currently have working code that requires the following where we increment the number 2 all the way up to 250

```
const form2 = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet2']  
   form2.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
    e.preventDefault()  
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form2)})  
     .then(response => console.log('Success!', response), alert('Successfully Submitted!')) 
     .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))  
   })
```

I would like to do this with a for loop or other non brute force technique but so far my attempts have failed

```
for (i = 0; i < 251; i++) { 
    const form[i] = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet',[i],']
    form[i].addEventListener('submit', e => {  
    e.preventDefault()  
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form[i])})  
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response), alert('Successfully Submitted!')) 
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))  
    })  
   }
```

Comment: A few mistakes: 1) if the `form` variable is already defined, you shouldn't redefined each list index. (second snippet, line 2). 2) you're missing a semicolon. (first snippet, line 1).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're trying to set the nth member of the list in `form`, but you don't seem to initialize `form` as an empty list. One way to fix this problem is to just redefine form as you pass through the list of integers (this avoids storing the whole list of forms in main memory):

```
for (let i=2; i<251; i++) {
  let form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet' + i];
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
}
```

Note also that if you want to start counting at 2, and want to continue counting until 251, you can use the loop above to achieve this effect. I hope that helps!

Comment: Just tested this and wasn't successful, I may be misunderstanding but it doesn't appear that in this loop the form number increments with the loop. In my current working code  there are 248 copies of the first snippet, each with their own number 2-250. It's terrible code but works.

Comment: @wmr123 can you try opening the Chrome browser, then opening the developer tools by clicking on the three dots in the upper-right-hand corner -> More Tools -> Developer Tools. Then click the console tab and paste the error you see in red there.